# Dropdown list and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange

Get time based on selected timezone :

I have a JS function that takes a time zone as an argument and returns the current time in that time zone.

```
function worldClock(zone) {
    var time = new Date()
    var gmtMS = time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
    var gmtTime = new Date(gmtMS)

    var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
    var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
    var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()

    if (hr < 10){
    hr = "0" + hr
    }
    if (min < 10){
    min = "0" + min
    }
    if (sec < 10){
    sec = "0" + sec
    }
    return hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
};
```

I also have a dropdown list with a list of cities and their time zone as a value.

```
 <select name="city">
        <option value="-4">Toronto</option>
        <option value="2">Stokholm</option>
        <option value="-5">New-York</option>
      </select>
```

I need the worldClock () function to be called when a certain city is selected; pass the value from the dropdown list as an argument and display the resulting value and city name: Toronto: 04:52:16; How can this be implemented?

Comment: add an event listener on the select, when it changes. get the selected option and pass the value to the function

Comment: Shortest simplest way: `<select name="city" onchange="worldClock(this.value);">` . I'm surprised you couldn't find that out with a very quick bit of research though. Handling the selection of an option from a dropdown is a _very_ common requirement, you would have found an example after a few moments. If you want a slightly more up-to-date way of doing things, look into Unobtrusive Event Handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Onchange event:

```js
function worldClock(zone) {
    var time = new Date()
    var gmtMS = time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
    var gmtTime = new Date(gmtMS)

    var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
    var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
    var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()

    if (hr < 10){
    hr = "0" + hr
    }
    if (min < 10){
    min = "0" + min
    }
    if (sec < 10){
    sec = "0" + sec
    }
    var output= hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    console.log(output);
    return output;
};
```

```html
 <select name="city" onchange="worldClock(this.value);">
        <option value="-4">Toronto</option>
        <option value="2">Stokholm</option>
        <option value="-5">New-York</option>
      </select>
```